# WhatsApp Business API error 1006 on every api call

Tags: kubernetes, postman, whatsapp, high-availability, whatsapi

I have deployed a multiconnect setup of the WhatsApp Business API client in Production Kubernetes enviroment, using the documentation for Minikube [Developer Setup: Multiconnect on Minikube](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/on-premises/get-started/installation/dev-multiconnect-on-minikube#step-2--get-the-whatsapp-business-api-client-configuration-files) as referece.

But when doing the first login, in order to get the auth token, i get the following error on Postman:

```json
{
    "meta": {
        "version": "v2.37.1",
        "api_status": "stable"
    },
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": 1006,
            "title": "Resource not found",
            "details": "URL path not found"
        }
    ]
}
```

All the containers are running:

```json
NAME                                           READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
mysql-dev-6cdc47979f-6f6t5                     1/1     Running     0          2d23h
whatsapp-coreapp-deployment-7bb4c6b8bc-qw946   1/1     Running     0          24m
whatsapp-coreapp-deployment-7bb4c6b8bc-zkj5z   1/1     Running     0          24m
whatsapp-master-deployment-84ffbdd48d-4rw8w    1/1     Running     0          24m
whatsapp-master-deployment-84ffbdd48d-zwvlq    1/1     Running     0          24m
whatsapp-web-deployment-74b99f4579-s44lp       1/1     Running     1          25m
whatsapp-web-deployment-74b99f4579-sn55t       1/1     Running     0          25m
```

And the given error happens on every call on Postman, not only when logging in (check health, get users, login, login admin, etc), all of them gives the same error:

```json
"code": 1006,
"title": "Resource not found",
"details": "URL path not found"
```

I've checked the container logs and i'ts returning 404 for every path called:

```json
[2021-12-20 12:40:57.546610] app.INFO: [dd610cd0d21e431fafafc737c323565e] Response:  {"meta":{"version":"v2.37.1","api_status":"stable"},"errors":[{"code":1006,"title":"Resource not found","details":"URL path not found"}]} []
[2021-12-20 12:40:57.548893] app.INFO: [dd610cd0d21e431fafafc737c323565e] Request POST_//v1/users/login returns 404 in 530.65 ms [] []
[2021-12-20 12:45:18.556704] app.ERROR: [4018a09ea0084f9fa82f843905de2b00] Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: No route found for "GET //v1/stats/app" (uncaught exception) at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php line 2 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"GET //v1/stats/app\" at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php:2, Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0): No routes found for \"//v1/stats/app\". at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/routing/Matcher/UrlMatcher.php:2)"} []
[2021-12-20 12:45:18.557154] app.INFO: [4018a09ea0084f9fa82f843905de2b00] Response:  {"meta":{"version":"v2.37.1","api_status":"stable"},"errors":[{"code":1006,"title":"Resource not found","details":"URL path not found"}]} []
[2021-12-20 12:45:18.557462] app.INFO: [4018a09ea0084f9fa82f843905de2b00] Request GET_//v1/stats/app returns 404 in 84.57 ms [] []
[2021-12-20 12:52:11.890507] app.ERROR: [5a84217237cc49e8bb9df953ac32c799] Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: No route found for "GET /auth/v1/login/" (uncaught exception) at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php line 2 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"GET /auth/v1/login/\" at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php:2, Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0): No routes found for \"/auth/v1/login/\". at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/routing/Matcher/UrlMatcher.php:2)"} []
[2021-12-20 12:52:11.890825] app.INFO: [5a84217237cc49e8bb9df953ac32c799] Response:  {"meta":{"version":"v2.37.1","api_status":"stable"},"errors":[{"code":1006,"title":"Resource not found","details":"URL path not found"}]} []
[2021-12-20 12:52:11.891043] app.INFO: [5a84217237cc49e8bb9df953ac32c799] Request GET_/auth/v1/login/ returns 404 in 84.07 ms [] []
[2021-12-20 12:52:12.088612] app.ERROR: [2b26c43f700640f190977bb797ec4448] Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: No route found for "GET /favicon.ico" (from "https://192.168.88.80:31599/auth/v1/login/") (uncaught exception) at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php line 2 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"GET /favicon.ico\" (from \"https://192.168.88.80:31599/auth/v1/login/\") at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php:2, Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0): No routes found for \"/favicon.ico\". at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/routing/Matcher/UrlMatcher.php:2)"} []
[2021-12-20 12:52:12.088863] app.INFO: [2b26c43f700640f190977bb797ec4448] Response:  {"meta":{"version":"v2.37.1","api_status":"stable"},"errors":[{"code":1006,"title":"Resource not found","details":"URL path not found"}]} []
[2021-12-20 12:52:12.089117] app.INFO: [2b26c43f700640f190977bb797ec4448] Request GET_/favicon.ico returns 404 in 82.22 ms [] []
```

Edit: Here's also the logs for the second replica of the webapp deployment

```json
Web server started
Starting web monitor loop ...
==> /var/log/lighttpd/error.log <==
2021-12-20 12:38:05: (server.c.1488) server started (lighttpd/1.4.55)
tail: cannot open '/var/log/whatsapp/web.log' for reading: No such file or directory
Setting up watches.
Watches established.
tail: '/var/log/whatsapp/web.log' has appeared;  following new file
[2021-12-20 12:52:24.295383] app.ERROR: [7c73b15c0a6c488fb5ac7703a4b337ec] Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: No route found for "GET /teste/" (uncaught exception) at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php line 2 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"GET /teste/\" at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php:2, Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0): No routes found for \"/teste/\". at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/routing/Matcher/UrlMatcher.php:2)"} []
[2021-12-20 12:52:24.302930] app.INFO: [7c73b15c0a6c488fb5ac7703a4b337ec] Response:  {"meta":{"version":"v2.37.1","api_status":"stable"},"errors":[{"code":1006,"title":"Resource not found","details":"URL path not found"}]} []
[2021-12-20 12:52:24.307525] app.INFO: [7c73b15c0a6c488fb5ac7703a4b337ec] Request GET_/teste/ returns 404 in 201.72 ms [] []
[2021-12-21 11:04:28.642518] app.ERROR: [7181dfea9e7b4e51adb41fc41571253f] Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: No route found for "POST //v1/users/login" (uncaught exception) at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php line 2 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"POST //v1/users/login\" at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php:2, Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0): No routes found for \"//v1/users/login\". at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/routing/Matcher/UrlMatcher.php:2)"} []
[2021-12-21 11:04:28.644938] app.INFO: [7181dfea9e7b4e51adb41fc41571253f] Response:  {"meta":{"version":"v2.37.1","api_status":"stable"},"errors":[{"code":1006,"title":"Resource not found","details":"URL path not found"}]} []
[2021-12-21 11:04:28.645501] app.INFO: [7181dfea9e7b4e51adb41fc41571253f] Request POST_//v1/users/login returns 404 in 87.15 ms [] []
[2021-12-21 11:05:29.180215] app.ERROR: [8ce236970e404d7b90d86ad53e774105] Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: No route found for "GET /auth/v1/login/" (uncaught exception) at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php line 2 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"GET /auth/v1/login/\" at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php:2, Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0): No routes found for \"/auth/v1/login/\". at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/routing/Matcher/UrlMatcher.php:2)"} []
[2021-12-21 11:05:29.180746] app.INFO: [8ce236970e404d7b90d86ad53e774105] Response:  {"meta":{"version":"v2.37.1","api_status":"stable"},"errors":[{"code":1006,"title":"Resource not found","details":"URL path not found"}]} []
[2021-12-21 11:05:29.181257] app.INFO: [8ce236970e404d7b90d86ad53e774105] Request GET_/auth/v1/login/ returns 404 in 26.28 ms [] []
[2021-12-21 11:05:29.332427] app.ERROR: [feb8c3253624422383421e253fc8ce73] Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: No route found for "GET /favicon.ico" (from "https://192.168.88.80:31599/auth/v1/login/") (uncaught exception) at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php line 2 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"GET /favicon.ico\" (from \"https://192.168.88.80:31599/auth/v1/login/\") at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php:2, Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0): No routes found for \"/favicon.ico\". at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/routing/Matcher/UrlMatcher.php:2)"} []
[2021-12-21 11:05:29.332971] app.INFO: [feb8c3253624422383421e253fc8ce73] Response:  {"meta":{"version":"v2.37.1","api_status":"stable"},"errors":[{"code":1006,"title":"Resource not found","details":"URL path not found"}]} []
[2021-12-21 11:05:29.333465] app.INFO: [feb8c3253624422383421e253fc8ce73] Request GET_/favicon.ico returns 404 in 21.29 ms [] []
```

And here is the service that got created for webapp:

```json
NAME                       TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)                               AGE
whatsapp-web-service       NodePort       10.110.67.166   <none>           443:31599/TCP                         22h
```

What could this be?

Comment: Hello @ReaperClown , did provided answer help you?

Comment: Not yet @kkopczak, pretty sure my problem is not on the URL but somewhere in the cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate admin auth token to call the APIs.
I did the following steps and it worked for me.
Note : I used docker-desktop inbuilt k8s single node cluster for POC on this issue.

```
1. Download the postman collection from this link:
   https://github.com/fbsamples/WhatsApp-Business-API-Postman-Collection
2. Follow the steps in this document:
   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/on-premises/get-started/postman
```

Do let me know if it worked for you as well.

Regards,

Prince Arora

Comment: Thanks! It turns out that my cluster was messed up after a broken PostgreSQL installation, completely recreating the cluster and reinstalling the WA Business API done the job.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a URL issue. Did you check the URL you are invoking?
As per the documentation in the link you have shared :

"port 443 inside the Webapp container is mapped to the port 32477 on the Kubernetes cluster.

You need to use https://your-minikube-cluster-ip:your-webapp-service-targetport (e.g., https://10.101.114.46:32477) as the API root URL when using the Postman collection."

But as per your logs, I see the port number used is 31599.
https://192.168.88.80:31599/auth/v1/login/

Regards,
Prince Arora

Comment: In the documentation the port 32477 was the one that got assigned in their example by the NodePort service, but in my case the port that was open for the webapp service was the 31599, in fact, if i try to send requests to the port 32477 i don't even get a response at all, as this port is not used by any service on my cluster, i get: `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.88.80:32477` when sending requests on that port. I have updated my question with the service as well.

Comment: Also added the logs for the second replica of the webapp pod